# Java JTextPane does not update its size when Character Attributes change

Tags: java, swing

I am programming a Swing based UI Component in Java 8, that basically displays multiple `JTextPane`s in a vertically scrollable Field and has a Toolbar for basic style manipulation (Font, Font Size, Bold, etc.)

For this I am using a `JPanel`, which also implements Scrollable inside a `JScrollPane`, that contains multiple `JTextPane`s using a vertical `BoxLayout`.

When I start this, it looks fine and all TextPanes are high enough to fit one line of text and scale when more is typed. The Problem occurs, when I change the font size. When the font size changes, the `JTextPane` should automatically resize to fit the new text, but when I use a button to change it, the size only changes when I click it twice.

Here are some screenshots to explain what I mean:
This is after the example starts, and I add some text to the top `JTextPane`. There are 2 TextPanes here.
[image: Normal Text]

This is after the first click to the button, which sets the font size to 30pt. The text is larger, but the `JTextPane` does not resize to fit it
[image: Large text cut off]

And this is after I click the button again. The `JTextPane` now scaled correctly
[image]

I already tried to call `invalidate`, `revalidate` and `repaint` manually on the `JTextPane` and its parents, but that had no effect.

The `JTextPane` also resizes when another Attribute is changed (e.g. bold) or the FontSize is change to another value. But it seems to always be one change behind.
So when the FontSize is changed to 20, then to 30, it will resize to fit 20pt font when the FontSize is set to 30pt.
Does anybody have an Idea what could cause the problem and how I can fix it?

Here is the code of the minimal example:

```java
public class TestEditorPanes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(getPanel());
        frame.setSize(720, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel editorPanel = new ScrollablePanel();
        editorPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(editorPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JTextPane textPane1 = new JTextPane();
        JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();

        editorPanel.add(textPane1);
        editorPanel.add(textPane2);

        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(editorPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Button sets Font size to 30
        JButton btnFontSize = new JButton("FontSize");
        btnFontSize.addActionListener(e -> {
            MutableAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrs, 30);
            textPane1.setCharacterAttributes(attrs, false);
        });

        mainPanel.add(btnFontSize, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    private static class ScrollablePanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 30;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 30;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for what I want it to.

When I tried debugging the problem, I noticed, that the Swing View, that renders the Component does not update its preferred size after changing character attributes for some reason.
Manually calling `updateUI()` on the `JTextPane` after changing the FontSize forces the UI to reload and compute a new size for the component.
This is the working version of the ActionListener for my minimal example:

```java
        btnFontSize.addActionListener(e -> {
            MutableAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrs, 30);
            textPane1.setCharacterAttributes(attrs, true);
            //Call updateUI to force recalculation of size
            textPane1.updateUI();
        });
```

Gilbert Le Blancs answer would also work, if I didn't need the `JTextPanes` to be directly below each other and seems to be the cleaner solution for me (notice he calls `setPreferredSize()` manually, so the UI does not have to calculate the size).

If someone knows the reason for this behavior or a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to create this GUI.

[image: Editor Panes GUI 1]

[image: Editor Panes GUI 2]

The main change I made was in your `ActionListener`.  By using the `StyledDocument` `setCharacterAttributes` method, I didn't have to select the text first.  It appears that setting the `JTextPane` font size caused the `JTextPane` to resize properly.

```
    JButton btnLargeFont = new JButton("Large Font");
    btnLargeFont.addActionListener(e -> {
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributes, 30);
        StyledDocument doc = textPane1.getStyledDocument();
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), attributes, true);
        textPane1.setFont(textPane1.getFont().deriveFont((float) 30));
    });
```

Here's the complete runnable code I used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TestEditorPanes implements Runnable {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestEditorPanes());
    }
    
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private MutableAttributeSet attributes;
    
    public TestEditorPanes() {
        this.attributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
         frame = new JFrame("Editor Panes");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         
         frame.add(getPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
         
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        JPanel editorPanel = new JPanel();
        editorPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        editorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        JTextPane textPane1 = new JTextPane();
        textPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributes, 14);
        textPane1.setCharacterAttributes(attributes, true);
        
        JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();
        textPane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));

        editorPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textPane1), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        editorPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textPane2), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(editorPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        // Button sets Font size to 14
        JButton btnNormalFont = new JButton("Normal Font");
        btnNormalFont.addActionListener(e -> {
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributes, 14);
            StyledDocument doc = textPane1.getStyledDocument();
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), attributes, true);
            textPane1.setFont(textPane1.getFont().deriveFont((float) 14));
        });
        buttonPanel.add(btnNormalFont, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        // Button sets Font size to 30
        JButton btnLargeFont = new JButton("Large Font");
        btnLargeFont.addActionListener(e -> {
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributes, 30);
            StyledDocument doc = textPane1.getStyledDocument();
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), attributes, true);
            textPane1.setFont(textPane1.getFont().deriveFont((float) 30));
        });
        buttonPanel.add(btnLargeFont, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        return mainPanel;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems the reason your code works, is that you set the preferredSize of both TextPanes, so they don't have to resize. I tried to just use a StyledDocument to change the font size, but it didn't work.

I need the textPanes to be sized dynamically to only fit the text they contain, so they are directly below each other.